# opencv java - detect all the rectangles and fill them with an image

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I am currently working on a solution for an automatic image edit.

And I have used Canny Edge Detection and Closing.

But What I ultimately want to accomplish is to find all the rectangles from blueprint and fill them with an image what I have.

I want to know the process that I need to take, not the exact code or solution!

Please suggest me what steps should I take to accomplish it, thx.

[Image that has the rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCkZS.png)

[Image that needs to go into all the rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrNdr.png)

[what i have done so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYL8v.jpg)

[2018-02-12 EDITTED(clean rectangle detected)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHD2H.png)

// I have done finding the rectangles and drawing lines over them, but the result is not really reliable than I expected(it draws line on rectangles those are not a parking space), and I do not know how to put an image on those rectangle instead of drawing line on them. please help me out!

P.S : Only in JAVA please !

Comment: Can you post example images and the results that you already have?

Comment: @user2518618 Done editting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you don't need Canny. Your image is really clean and edges are really visible already. A simple Threshold, will work better.

For rectangle detection take a look at this example (included with opencv) that uses findcontours and checks the angles: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/squares.cpp

In your case, you can skip the Canny step because you don't have gradients. You may need to modify the filtering, like side dimensions for your case.

Once the rectangles look good, you just need to copy your image in the location. If rectangles are rotated, you will have to rotate your image as well.

EDIT:
To copy the small image onto the big image you can do the following

```
Mat submatImg = bigImage.submat(new Rect(x, y, smallImage.width(), smallImage.height());
smallImage.copyTo(submatImg);
```

If you need to do resizing and rotations, take a look at [geometric transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html)

Comment: I am sorry that I didnt mention that canny and closing are for special cases(when a source image is dirty). And what I actually wanted to ask was "how to copy my image on rectangles I found".. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: And If you see the result image I have done so far, I found rectangles a lot(Highligted with thick gray lines) but unwanted targets as well. Is there any technique you would suggest to get rectangles only from the parking spaces?

Comment: Once you have the contours, you have to filter them by number of vertices, their angles, dimensions of the sides, orientation of the sides. The example already keeps only if they have 90 degree angles and sides lengths > 1000. You have to add more conditions for your case

Comment: Findcontours gives you the location of the vertices. From that, you can find the top left corner of the rectangle and then copy the image there. Copy is very basic, so you can find many examples online. You may have to resize or rotate as well, but again there are many examples and if you are really stuck in one of the steps, you can post a specific question for that

Comment: thanks for your guidance. I did not know that Findcontours give me the vertices :) So you mean there is a way to copy image on given 4 vertices! I will work on that and ask more specificly If I get stucked.

Comment: I am sorry to call you again, but I editted my post again and the last link is what I have done so far. Unfortunately, I only have succeeded in detecting a clear rectangle(which doesnt include diagonal line). I came up with an idea of filling those rectangles which have diagonal line first, and then detect for the rectangles after. But I have failed detecting those rectangles. I have tried to detect them from the approxCurve.total()'s return value but it never worked out. Is there any idea that I can include those rectangles in detection ? Thanks for reading :)

Comment: P.S. The Text "RECT" is a sign of detection.